# Conditionals, past perfect vs would

Tags: conditionals, conditional-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, deontic-vs-epistemic, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

I was reading a book and I can't understand why past perfect is used in the sentence below:

> *The signal from successive eclipse has less and less distance to travel, so it arrives earlier than if Jupiter had remained at a constant distance.*

Why can't it be...*if Jupiter would remain*...?

Comment: Simply because that is ungrammatical here in standard English.

Comment: First, that sentence has other grammatical problems with it. (The plural agreement isn't correct, so it might not have been written by a native English speaker. It should be *from successive eclipse**s***, which could lead to several other changes to the sentence.) And *would* is wrong; in standard English, we only use *would* in an *if* clause when it means *willing to*.

Comment: It can't be _would_; but it could be _remained_, simple past, instead of _had remained_. The past perfect in subordinate clauses is rarely necessary in speech; past will do unless there's an unusual situation.

Comment: The only reason I can see for using *had remained* rather than *remained* is that the light from the eclipse takes time to get from Jupiter to Earth. But this is a pretty slim reason; since Jupiter is moving much more slowly than the speed of light, the one would expect that the travel time of light could be ignored in this situation.

Comment: Caro, I recommend you visit our sister site for [ell.se].